# Make child element cover parent

Tags: html, css, image, parent-child

What I want to do is to make a image fill it's parent element.

```
<div class="parent">
    <img src="image.jpg">
</div>
```

If in my CSS I use:

```
img{
   width: 100%;
}
```

It will make the image fill it's parent but just horizontally but if the image is smaller vertically it will leave a empty space. Like this:

[image]

What I really want to do is to make the image to cover the whole thing. I also don't want to use overflow: hidden, because if the image is way bigger than it's parent the image will be cut. I want to make the image to resize and cover it's parent like using background-size: cover, with the difference that this is not a CSS background but inner element.

Can someone help me please?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want the image to stretch vertically, as in without preserving aspect ratio?

Comment: @Asad No, I want to preserve aspect ratio, that's why I didn't use height: 100% like with the width.

Comment: You need to decide between cutting off part of the image and preserving aspect ratio. You can't do both and still fit a container of arbitrary size (short of resizing the container to fit the image).

Answer (score 3):

You can use some css and a wrapper element to accomplish this. The size applied to the parent is for example only and doesn't need to be there. You will need `overflow:hidden` though.

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="img-container">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent{
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.img-container{
    position:relative;
    top: -50%; 
    left: -50%; 
    width: 200%; 
    height: 200%;    
}
.img-container img{    
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    margin: auto; 
    min-width: 50%;
    min-height: 50%;
}
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dquN6/

Adapted from http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 0):

If you want your image to cover its parent without preserving the aspect ratio, you only need to add `height:100%` in the css of your image. Like this:

```
img {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```